# Opus will not be imported despite being installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, opus

I have installed the latest version of opus for python 3.4 using pip in gitbash

```
$ pip install --upgrade opuslib
Requirement already up-to-date: opuslib in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
```

Despite this, when I attempt to import it, I'll receiver an error that it is not installed

```
import opuslib
import opuslib.api
import opuslib.api.encoder
import opuslib.api.decoder
```

...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\__Basic-discord-bot\bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    import opuslib
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\opuslib\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .classes import Encoder, Decoder  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\opuslib\classes.py", line 11, in <module>
    import opuslib.api.decoder
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\opuslib\api\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    'Could not find opus library. Make sure it is installed.')
Exception: Could not find opus library. Make sure it is installed.
```

Comment: Look in the test files in the github repository how it is imported; do the same.

Comment: still getting the same error, unfortunately

Comment: use pip3 for python 3.x

Comment: What do you see in your c:\python\lib\site-packages directory is opuslib really there? Or is it a sub-directory of something else? I vaguely recall having a problem once, where the target dir was a sub-dir of an egg dir.

Comment: opuslib is definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

View the `__init.py__` inside C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\opuslib\api folder, line 20. It checks whether opus is installed or not in your machine, and the result, it cannot find 'opus library'. You only pip install python's opuslib, the python binding for opus library. Install opus in your machine.  If you are using mac, try `brew install opus`.

Answer (score 0):

If on a mac, I found the Homebrew 'lib' directory, heres my python interpreter:

```
>>> find_library("/usr/local/opus")
>>> find_library("/usr/local/lib/opus")
>>> find_library("/usr/local/lib/libopus")
>>> '/usr/local/lib/libopus.dylib'
```

Answer (score 0):

**brew install opus** works well on mac m1/m2
just need to copy path given by brew for opus library and then navigate to that library you will find your path at  **lib/libopus.0**